# SIFT from OpenCV in kaggle script editor

Tags: python, opencv, sift, kaggle

I am trying to use SIFT from OpenCV for image object recongnition, so I started with this code to test the environment:

```
import cv2 
img = cv2.imread('../input/train_2/2.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)
img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)
cv2.imwrite('sift_keypoints.jpg',img)
```

when i run the code i got this error :

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'

It seems that the OpenCV package installed does not support SIFT. 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

SIFT is part from the [opencv-contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) package, which is not shipped with the opencv package contain experimental and non-free modules - so be aware of the licensing and so...

You should build opencv with the extra modules, you need to:

1. Download or clone the opencv-contrib
2. use this flag in the cmake command line: `cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <other_flags> <opencv_source_directory>`